# Diablo 3 license transfer?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm looking into getting another computer and am wondering if I'd be able to continue my D3 account on another PC. Will my valid. code still be honored the second time I install on the new comp? Or would I have to purchase another..?

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: All you will have to do is install the game and then access your account.  This question doesn't need more then a single sentence to answer it.

Answer (score 15):

You shouldn't need to enter the licence key a second time.  When you install Diablo 3, it associates the licence key with your Battle.net account - not with the installed copy of Diablo 3.  Once you have associated the licence key, you can log on to any instance of Diablo 3 with your Battle.net account and have access to your characters, etc.

What that means in your case is that you should be able to install Diablo 3 with no issues, and then just log in with your existing Battle.net account without worrying about licence keys.

Answer (score 3):

Diablo doesn't link your CD key to an installation or computer, rather it links to your Battle.net account. You can install Diablo III on any PC you like with your CD, but you can only link the CD key that came with your box to one Battle.net account. Any account with a valid key registered against it can then use any installation to login to Diablo III and play as much as they like.